# Power BI Embedded : Issues with MS Edge and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, powerbi, microsoft-edge, powerbi-embedded

We have an Application Developed in ASP.NET inside which we have added a few embedded Power Bi Dashboards using iFrame.

The Dashboard is working as expected in Chrome and Firefox but facing the following issues with IE and Edge.

> - On IE the Dashboard in not being Displayed when viewed from the Embedded Application, But can be viewed from the app.Powerbi.com.
> - On Edge, it is displaying a Request access Button and once the user clicks the same it takes him to the app.powerbi.com and there the user is able to view the Dashboard without any additional actions.

I tried clearing the Cache and Cookies but still no luck.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I try to create ASP.NET site and try to embed PowerBI report using Iframe. I made a test with IE 11 and MS Edge on 3 machines but report display fine in all browser. Here are the test results. Edge 42: https://i.postimg.cc/NMFKDmg8/91-edge42.png Edge 44: https://i.postimg.cc/Dmkm7N15/92-edge44.png IE 11: https://i.postimg.cc/xTvLcGqq/93-IE11.png I suggest you to check the latest updates for your Windows and try to install it. than after again try to check for the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT are you just using the iframe directly or using any Embedded Token for authentication? can you please add more details

Comment: I use the Embed option from PowerBI to generate the Iframe code and use it in the ASP.NET site.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, try to add the domain "https://*.powerbi.com" to the Trusted Sites list, in Internet Options / Security / Trusted Sites.
In Edge, I have the same problem (there is not a "trusted sites list" for Edge).